# How to get a symmetrical sub list and then get the sum of that sub list?

Tags: python, list, integer

What the code does: Takes a Python list of integers as input and searches for a 'symmetrical' inner-portion of the list then it takes that inner portion and gets the sum of it.

Symmetry occurs if the value of the ith element from the start of the list is equal to the value of the ith element from the end of the list.

Examples of what i want:

```
symmetrical_sum([10,11,12,11,12]) == ([11, 12, 11], 34)
symmetrical_sum([9,99,88,8,77,7,77,8,88,10,100]) == ([88, 8, 77, 7, 77, 8, 88], 353)
symmetrical_sum([10,8,7,5,9,8,15]) == ([8, 7, 5, 9, 8], 37)
```

Is there any short-coded solution to get the outputs in the examples given above? I have a correct coded version but it is more than 30 lines of code and would like to know if there is shorter way.

Comment: what is the logic behind the output of last line? `[8, 7, 5, 9, 8]` is not symmetrical.

Comment: if you are interested in the shortest possible code that provide a desired output, this is the subject of "code golf" - however this is more of a recreational activity.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def symmetrical_sum(a):
    dup=[x for n, x in enumerate(a) if x in a[:n]] #to get the duplicate
    
    to_int = int(''.join(map(str,dup))) #change duplicate into int
    dup1_index=a.index(to_int) #index the first duplicate
    dup2_index=a.index(to_int,dup1_index+1) #index the second duplicate
    portion=a[dup1_index:dup2_index+1] #get the symetric portion
    total = sum(portion) #sum the elements in portion
    tuple1 = (portion,total) #create tuple
    return tuple1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive function as follows:

```
def sym(L):
    if L[0] == L[-1]:
        lis, sum_list = L, sum(L)
        answer = f'inner-portion: {lis}, sum: {sum_list}'
        return answer
    else:
        return sym(L[1:-1])
```

Note that the above will work for a list input with odd number items (that is the length is an odd number)and a single item list but not an empty list. A more wholistic approach is the following:

```
def symmetrical_sum(a):

    index_from_start = 0
    index_from_end= len(a)-1
    sym_list= []
    while index_from_start<=index_from_end:
        if a[index_from_start] == a[index_from_end]:
            sym_list= a[index_from_start:index_from_end+1]
            break
        else:
            index_from_start += 1
            index_from_end -= 1
    return sym_list, sum(sym_list)
```

QED :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `numpy`:

1. get a list of booleans representing the condition if `i`th element from beginning and end are equal
2. find indices where the boolean values are `True`
3. The min value represent where symmetry starts and max value is where it ends, so slice the list array to get the "symmetrical" sub-list
4. return the new list and its sum as a tuple

**Following code should work for the input and output you posted:**

```py
import numpy as np

def sym_sum(arr):
    l = len(arr)-1
    bool_arr = np.array([x==arr[l-i] for i,x in enumerate(arr)])
    idx_arr = np.where(bool_arr==True)[0]
    if len(idx_arr):
        res = arr[min(idx_arr):max(idx_arr)+1]
    else:
        res = []
    return (res, sum(res))
```

**If you need actual symmetrical output use:**

```py
import numpy as np

def get_sym(arr):
    l = len(arr) - 1
    bool_arr = np.array([x == arr[l - i] for i, x in enumerate(arr)])
    idx_arr = np.where(bool_arr == False)[0]
    if len(idx_arr):
        return get_sym(arr[min(idx_arr)+1:max(idx_arr)])
    else:
        return (arr, sum(arr))
```

Here we recursively call the function until the unsymmetrical portions are completely striped.

Answer (score 0):

In pure python this can be achieved like this:

```
def symmetrical_sum(a):


inner_portion = []
  sum = 0;
  start = 0;
  for i in a:
    end = len(a) - (start + 1);
    if a[start] == a[end]:
      inner_portion = a[start:(end+1)];
      for i in inner_portion:
        sum+= i
      break
    start+= 1
  return (inner_portion, sum)

print(symmetrical_sum([10,11,12,11,12])) #([11, 12, 11], 34)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mid = float(len(a))/2
my_list =a[int(Mid - .5): int(Mid + .5)]
my_list_total =sum(my_list)
get_total= (my_list,my_list_total)
```

## answer return get_total  ([5], 5)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).